# Differentiability of Nemytskii operator on Sobolev space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, elliptic-pde

I am trying to consider hypothesis on $g$ such that the operator
$$ H_0^1 (\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega), \qquad v \mapsto g(v) $$
is $\mathcal C^1$. As additional hypothesis $\Omega$ is bounded and $g(0) = 0$.

I believe that $g \in W^{2,\infty} (\mathbb R)$ is sufficient, but I am quite stuck on the proof.

Thanks in advance,

D

Comment: It seems like you're on the right track. It's just the chain rule, no?

Comment: Basically, yes. But you have to proof the convergence
$$   \frac{g(v + w) - g(v)}{|w|} \overset{ L^2 }\to g'(v) w, \quad \text{as } w \overset{H^1} \to 0  $$
which presents some technical difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

In the realm of Sobolev spaces, if $k>\frac{\dim(F)}2$, for the composition mapping $H^{k+l}(F,\mathbb R) \times H^k(F,F) \to H^k(F,\mathbb R)$, left translations are $C^l$ and right translations are smooth; i.e., composition is $C^l$ in the right hand side variable, and is smooth in the left hand side variable. This is folklore; for a detailed recent proof see

- H. Inci,T. Kappeler and P. Topalov, On the Regularity of the Composition of Diffeomorphisms, Memoirs of the American Mathematical Society, vol. 226 (American Mathematical Society, 2013).

In your case we have a left translation, but you are not above the Sobolev threshold with $v$, in general.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will go on looking for translations instead of Nemitskii operators and I am sure the reference you gave me (which I have already shifted through) will be very useful in the future.

However, I need far less regularity on the result, since $g \circ v$ need only be $L^2$. Ultimately my aim is to use $\langle g(v), \cdot \rangle_{L^2}$ as an element in $H^{-1}$ for a weak formulation of a PDE so conditions of the type $s > \frac n 2$ are not of much use, as $s$ should  be $2$. I would also like Lipschitz-like conditions on $g$.

Comment: Hello can you please help on the question I asked here https://mathoverflow.net/q/337841/108824

Answer (score 1):

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$
[image: Part 1 of Nemytskii operator differentiability]
[image: Part 2 of Nemytskii operator differentiability]

Comment: In the proof of Lemma 2.1 in place of the exponent $\frac 12\,(q-2)$ there should be $q^{-1}(q-2)\,$, and in the proof of Theorem 2.2 in place of the zero vector $\boldsymbol 0_E$ of $E$ there should be the representative $\boldsymbol 0=\Omega\times\{\kern.3mm 0\kern.3mm\} \,$.

Comment: I believe globally bounded and Lipschitzian are quite strong assumptions, and can be relaxed.

Comment: Do you have any idea for a proof with the "relaxed" assumptions, and what would they be? The assumptions in Theorem 2.2 are just a bit weaker than being in $W^{2,+\infty}(\mathbb R)$ that the OP believed sufficient.