# Superposition operator from Sobolev space to Lebesgue space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, differential-operators

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded, connected set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with smooth boundary. I am wondering under what conditions on the real function $f(x):\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ the superposition operator $F(w)(x,y)=f(w(x,y))$ defines a

1. Well-posed operator form $H^1(\Omega)$ to $L^2(\Omega)$?

   2. A differentiable map form $H^1(\Omega)$ to $L^2(\Omega)$?

---

Note that functions in $H^1(\Omega)$ are not necessarily continuous, but $H^1(\Omega)$ continuously embeds into $L^p(\Omega)$, $1\le p<\infty$.

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181460/differentiability-of-nemytskii-operator-on-sobolev-space) is a similar question, and the ideas [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181460/differentiability-of-nemytskii-operator-on-sobolev-space/244472#244472) *may* be applicable, depending on the goal.

Comment: @TaQ  Hello, can you please help on the question asked here
https://mathoverflow.net/q/337841/108824