# Is $f$ defined by $f(x) = t\mapsto G(t , x(t))$ differentiable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Let us consider $X = AC([0 , 1] , \mathbb{R}^n)$, and $Y=L^{1} ([0,1] , \mathbb{R}^n )$ as Banach spaces with their usual norms.  Let $G: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuously differentiable function.

My question: is the function $f : X \to Y$ defined by 
$$ f(x)(t) = G(t , x(t))  \quad \quad \text{for all }~ x\in X $$
continuously differentiable?

At first glance it seems $f$ is just a composition of two differentiable functions, but it is not. Because $G$ is defined on the finite dimension space $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n$ not $\mathbb{R} \times Y$ !

Comment: Look for Nemytskii operators

Comment: note that you should write $f(x)(t)$ instead of $f(x(t))$, and that the $F$ mentioned has no role at all in the question.

Comment: Thanks I'll edite those.

Comment: @PietroMajer but, nemytskii operator should be defined from the same set which is the domain of $G$ right?

Comment: @PietroMajer I couldn't find anything about differentiability of  Nemytskii operators on those spaces I mentioned.

Comment: The paper [On NEMYTSKIJ Operators in Lp‐Spaces of Abstract Functions](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/mana.19921550110) is more general but includes results on your setting. Use that your $X$ is included in a certain Lebesgue space.

Comment: @Hannes As soon as I get access to thevpaper I'll check that. Thank You

Comment: @Hannes I checked that paper. It seems it does not cover my setting. In that paper I have to consider $X= Y = R^n$ ans  $S=[0,1]$, then the Nemytskii operator oprator, $A$ becomes a mapping from $L^1 ([0,1] , R^n)$ to $L^1 ([0,1] , R^n)$. While I want it maps $AC ([0,1] , R^n)$ to $ L^1 ([0,1] , R^n )$.

Comment: Uh, where should the requirement $p=1$, so $L^1([0,1];R^n)$ as the domain of the operator, come from? (And even then, if some theorem says that the Nemytskii operator is a mapping with the desired properties between the $L^1$ spaces, that in particular implies that it is a mapping with the desired properties from $AC$ to $L^1$ due to embedding, no?)

Comment: @Hannes No requirement on $p$ in the paper. I'm just saying, I only need $p=q=1$, so let's focus on this case. The first thing paper requires (in Theorem 7) is that $p$ and $q$ has to be different numbers, so this fails in my setting. Secondly it is just talking about differentiability not continuously diff (this in minor though).  And I'm not sure what exactly embedding property you talk about, can mention a link about that?  Thank You

Comment: @Hannes  oh Please look at the introduction of the section 3. the authors say  "According to results of KRASNOSEL'SKIJ a. $ [5]$, chpt. $20.2$, the FRECHET differentiability of $A$ implies the affin linearity of $A$ if  $  p = q $  !!

Comment: I have no idea why you insist on having $p=q=1$. The space $AC([0,1];R^n)$ is continuously embedded even in $L^\infty([0,1];R^n)$. Any result for when the Nemytskii operator is continuously differentiable or whatever you want from $L^\infty([0,1];R^n)$ to $L^1([0,1];R^n)$ will imply the same for $AC([0,1];R^n)$ to $L^1([0,1];R^n)$.

Comment: @Hannes  Because I look at $AC$ as $R^n \times L^{1}$.

Comment: Uh, in the sense of $(g_0,g) \in R^n \times L^1([0,1];R^n)$ defining a function $f(x) = g_0 + \int_0^x g(t) dt$? Then $f$ is absolutely continuous, and if you give that vector space of functions the $W^{1,1}([0,1];R^n)$ norm (where then by construction $f' = g$), then have the embedding as I said.

Comment: @Hannes Thanks. But actually I still dont know how properly use the Theorem 7 to fit my setting. In the embedding you said $p = \infty$ and $q=1$ this case has not been covered by the Theorem !

Comment: Generally: If a function $F \colon X_0 \to Y_0$ is continuously differentiable, and $X \hookrightarrow X_0$ and $Y_0 \hookrightarrow Y$, then $F$ it is also continuously differentiable if considered as a function $X \to Y$..

Comment: @Hannes Thank You. Just to make sure for last time, since $AC[0,1]$ is continuously  embedded in $L^{\infty}$ , and $L^{\infty}$  continuously embedded in $L^{1}$ then continuously differentiability of the  Nemytskii operator, say $F: L^{\infty} \to L^{\infty}$ implies the continuously differentiability of the  Nemytskii operator, say $F: AC[0,1] \to L^{1}$. Right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly :-)